# C# Encrypt and Decrypt a File Stream: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Tags: c#, encryption

I need to encrypt and decrypt file - streams so the data that is written to the file system is encrypted already and gets decrypted in memory only after reading.

I wrote a small demo - program:

```
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace House
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static string PassPhrase => "JustATest";
        public static string PathToFile = @"C:\TMP\test.bin";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var iv = new byte[]
            {
                222, 49, 46, 125, 250, 194, 122, 241, 234, 22, 151, 76, 181, 83, 149, 92, 195, 11, 146, 213, 195, 40, 0,
                183, 84, 149, 185, 100, 250, 156, 123, 75
            };

            if (File.Exists(PathToFile))
                File.Delete(PathToFile);

            var set = CreateData();

            using (var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PassPhrase, 100);
                var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(32);

                symmetricKey.BlockSize = 256;
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, iv);

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(PathToFile, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                        formatter.Serialize(cryptoStream, set);
                        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                        fileStream.Flush(true);
                    }
                }
            }

            using (var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PassPhrase, 100);
                var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(32);

                symmetricKey.BlockSize = 256;
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, iv);

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(PathToFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                        var deserialized = (DataSet)formatter.Deserialize(cryptoStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static DataSet CreateData()
        {
            var customer = new DataTable("customer");
            var customerId = customer.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            customer.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            var order = new DataTable("orders");
            order.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            var fkCustomerId = order.Columns.Add("FkCustomerId", typeof(int));
            order.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            var set = new DataSet();
            set.Tables.Add(customer);
            set.Tables.Add(order);
            set.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("r1", customerId, fkCustomerId));

            var r1 = set.Tables["customer"].NewRow();
            r1[0] = 5;
            r1[1] = "Test";
            set.Tables["customer"].Rows.Add(r1);

            var r2 = set.Tables["orders"].NewRow();
            r2[0] = 1;
            r2[1] = 5;
            r2[2] = "test";
            set.Tables["orders"].Rows.Add(r2);
            return set;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program the following exception is thrown as soon as it comes to data de-serialization: **System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 
'Binary stream 'XX' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.'**

Right now I am running out of ideas, does anyone see the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you create a minimal, compilable reproduction? It seems to me that the code you posted is way more complicated than it needs to be to reproduce the problem.

Comment: sidenote: `FileMode.Create` already 'deletes and recreates' the file. So `File.Delete` is not required and also does not guarantee that in the meantime the same file has been re-created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using different keys for encryption and decryption. The following lines:

```
var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PassPhrase, 100);                
var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(32);
```

Generate *random* salt of specified size (100 bytes) and then derives a key of given size from your pass phrase and that random salt. That means when executed two times - this will produce two different keys - for that reason decryption fails in your case.

So to decrypt you either need to have a key which was used to encrypt (in your code - by for example moving key generation out of both encrypt and decrypt blocks) OR you need both passphase and salt which was used to encrypt (you can get and set salt using `password.Salt` property, or you can pass it to constructor of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`).